# ChronoUnit.between() for a converted java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, time

This works (returns 0):

```
ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(
        LocalDateTime.now(),
        LocalDateTime.now());
```

This fails:

```
ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(
        ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(new Date().toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"),
        LocalDateTime.now());
```

With this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 2016-10-27T14:05:37.617 of type java.time.LocalDateTime
...
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZoneId from TemporalAccessor: 2016-10-27T14:05:37.617 of type java.time.LocalDateTime
at java.time.ZoneId.from(ZoneId.java:466)
at java.time.ZonedDateTime.from(ZonedDateTime.java:553)
... 3 more
```

Does anyone know how I can use a java.util.Date in a ChronoUnit.between()?

Comment: side note: a `)` is missing

Comment: How do you expect to compare a ZonedDateTime with a LocalDateTime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of [ChronoUnit.between](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) method says:

> This calculates the amount in terms of this unit. The start and end points are supplied as temporal objects and must be of compatible types. The implementation will convert the second type to be an instance of the first type before the calculating the amount.

It is trying to convert the `LocalDateTime` to a `ZonedDateTime`. `LocalDateTime` doesn't have the Zone information and causes the error.

If you use a ZonedDateTime as the second parameter it works correctly:

```
ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(new Date().toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC")), ZonedDateTime.now())
```

Answer (score 3):

A LocalDateTime has no timezone.  There is no way to compare it to an Instant or ZonedDateTime, which represent exact points in time.

Since your question is about comparing a Date, the easiest way is to compare an Instant with an Instant:

```
long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(
    new Date().toInstant(),
    Instant.now());
```